# DATEDIFF for sql query execution time giving error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using this code segment for calculating the query execution time .

```
USE Item

DECLARE @dtStart DATETIME = GETDATE()

SELECT * FROM item

SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, GETDATE(), @dtstart)
```

But it's showing me this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dtstart"

Two days earlier I used the same statements . It was working fine but now it's giving error.

I'm unable to solve this . Help ?
I'm quite new to the database thing

I'm using SQL server 2008 , visual studio 2012

I would have uploaded the image of the exact t-sql editor window itself with the question but the reputation restriction right now doesn't allow me to

Comment: Please supply the line number provided on the error.

Comment: May I suggest you use `GETUTCDATE()` to avoid localization to your time zone and just in case you decide to use this timing method for longer running tasks that might span time zone changes (summer/winter time).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shown here.

Comment: Also, is your query exactly as above? You are treating the identifier "Item" as both a database and a table/view

Comment: Have you inserted some `GO` batch separators into this query between when it "was working" and "now"?

Comment: @NeilMoss : line number is 7
and yeah , my query is exactly as above . "item" is both my database and table

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : No I didn't use any go tags in my code earlier or today .

Comment: @MikaelEriksson : yeah I checked online also . And almost same of the query I found too but even that is not working for me .

Comment: Okay - one final guess - are you working in an instance with a case sensitive collation? What happens if you ensure that all of the variable references use consistent casing? What do you get if you run `Select SERVERPROPERTY(N'Collation')`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : By running the query m getting 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: I assume you also tried the other experiment I suggested (i.e. consistently casing the variable's name) and nothing changed?

Comment: Maybe this is some horrid unicode thing with cut-and-paste. What happens if you delete the "@dtStart" strings completely, and re-type them?

Comment: @NeilMoss : yes sir .. I've tried that too many a times

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Ok I'll try that one too and let you know today

Comment: What platform are you using to execute the query? SQL Management Studio? Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Also, if using SQL Management Studio, please can you generate and post the xml version of the Estimated execution plan. It may fail to generate at all, but let's see.... From your query editor window, right click, choose "Display Estimated Execution Plan" and if it displays a plan diagram, right click in that diagram and choose "Show Execution Plan Xml"

Comment: @NeilMoss : I'm using Transact-SQL editor in visual studio itself

Comment: It's working now .
Mistake I was doing was that I was executing statements one at a time . But when I selected all at once and clicked on execute it worked well . Didn't know it matters :/

Comment: Well that explains everything :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@dtstart"

itself is self explanatory.

You need to provide the datatype of the datetime variable `@dtStart`

```
USE Item
DECLARE @dtStart DATETIME
SET @dtStart = GetDate()
SELECT * FROM item
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond,@dtstart,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Technically speaking, the `@dtstart` and  `GETDATE()` parameters  to [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) should be swapped or the result will be negative.

Comment: @BernhardHofmann:- Yes that was a good call. Updated my answer!

Comment: @user3414693 : I've tried this too but by doing this , only difference I'm getting is that instead of last line , I'm getting same error in 3rd line itself.

Comment: @IshanAg24:- Are you sure that the item table and Item db is correct?

Comment: @IshanAg24:- I have just changed the db name and table name as present in my local server and the query is working fine. So I am quiet sure that this may be because of the case sensitivity issue or may be that the table or DB problem!

Comment: @user3414693  : I just tried by keeping the db name as item/Item both and changing the table name as location . But still getting same problem

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
USE Item
DECLARE @dtStart DATETIME
SET @dtStart = GetDate()
SELECT * FROM item
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond,GETDATE(),@dtstart)
```

Comment: Did this but instead of getting error in last line , I'm only getting the error in 3rd line itself